# Having issues creating conditional outputs with logstash using metadata fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, metadata

I want to send winlogbeat data to a separate index than my main index. I have configured winlogbeat to send it's data to my logstash server and i can confirm that i have received the data.

This is what i do currently:

```
output {
  if [@metadata][beat] == "winlogbeat" {
    elasticsearch {
                                hosts => ["10.229.1.12:9200", "10.229.1.13:9200"]
                                index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
                                user => logstash_internal
                                password => password
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
  else {
     elasticsearch {
                                hosts => ["10.229.1.12:9200", "10.229.1.13:9200"]
                                index => "logstash-%{stuff}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
                                user => logstash_internal
                                password => password
                   }
       }
   }
}
```

However, i cannot start logstash using this configuration. If i remove the if statements and only use one elasticsearch output, the one which handles regular logstash data, it works.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with the brackets from your configuration. To fix your code please see below:

```
output {
    if [@metadata][beat] == "winlogbeat" {

        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.229.1.12:9200", "10.229.1.13:9200"]
            index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
            user => logstash_internal
            password => password
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }

    } else {

        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.229.1.12:9200", "10.229.1.13:9200"]
            index => "logstash-%{stuff}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
            user => logstash_internal
            password => password
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this sorts your issue.